# CSS issue regarding radiobuttons

Tags: html, css

I have HTML, which I cannnot change and I need to apply CSS styling for input elements inside it (type:radio). But I cannot do this. Already spent hours trying to make it work. Is it even possible?

Here is an example of what I want to implement:

http://jsfiddle.net/Raimondss/pKdr4/26/

```
.radio {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #666;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

One of the `<input>` elements is inside `<span>` element, and because of that it is not working like other buttons. I have a requirement to put all my `<input>` elements inside this `<span>` elements, but then it just stop working for me. Does anyone have any suggestions regarding how this can be done and how should I change my CSS? How can I put `<input>` elements inside `<span>` tags and still have working functionality?

P.S. `<input>` element can also have class.

Comment: If you want a CSS-only solution, you can't without changing your markup. By nesting the first input element in a `<span>` element, you will be unable to traverse one level up the DOM and access the neighbouring `<label>` element. CSS does not have the ability to go "upstream".

Comment: Terry, thank you for your comment. I also could not find any information on how to implement this using CSS-only, but I wanted to be sure, that there is no workaround for this. I am working with ADF and it generates HTML for `<af:selectBooleanRadio>` element with `<input>` element inside `<span>`. Why would they do that?

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before
```

Means any `<label>` that is adjacent to a `input[type="radio"]:checked`. The first one isn't adjacent because of the span.

If you put them all in spans it doesn't work, for that same reason.

**Option 1**

If you can use javascript you can mark the `span` of the selected `radio` and use something like

```
span.checked-in-me + label:before
```

**Option 2**

If putting the label in the `span` together with the `input` is an option - that can help.

Comment: Hi JNF!  **Option 2** is not an option for me in my case, because I cannot change HTML. But, maybe, I will come up with something using **Option 1**. Thank you for this one!